# Editing the configuration file using python script

Tags: python, automated-tests

I have a config file like below

```
....
....
MIN_TOKENS='30 50'  # can be a sequence of integers
STRIDE='2 0'  # can be a sequence of integers
SIMILARITY='1.0 0.95'  # can be a sequence of values <= 1
....
....
```

I need to edit the parameters to each of the above configurations(if needed) and test if the edited parameter suits my need by running my application. I need to automate this process using python script.

For example:
I need to change the config file to something like

```
....
....
MIN_TOKENS='30 50'  
STRIDE='2'  
SIMILARITY='0.75'  
....
....
```

and then run my application. However, the parameters should be automatically generated within range and I shouldn't manually feed them. I'm not familiar with python. Could someone tell me how to approach this.

Comment: How are the parameters used? Can you send the values directly to the program which uses them rather than edit the config file?

Comment: That can't be done

Comment: can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do.
your config.ini will be something like below

```
[Device]
MIN_TOKENS = "34 45"
STRIDE = 45
SIMILARITY = '0.75'
```

conf.py

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
config_file = "config.ini"
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.optionxform = str
parser.read(config_file)

def set_config(section, option, value):
    if parser.has_section(section):
        parser.set(section, option , value)
        with open(config_file, "w") as conf_file:
            parser.write(conf_file)
            return True
set_config('Device','MIN_TOKENS','"34 20"')
```

output

```
[Device]
MIN_TOKENS = "34 20"
STRIDE = 45
SIMILARITY = '0.75'
```

Comment: The option and value shouldn't  be set manually. It is like generating automatic test case and test it

Comment: yes sure, you can do it, if option exists then it will update else will create new. but the section name should be there

Comment: @Jab this example uses hard coded values, but you can easily modify it to use a variable instead.

Comment: @Arun - what if my config file doesn't have a named section?

Comment: It is like club attributes under a tag, you can have any name as section